# Why does Blender crash when I open the shading tab?

Tags: error

I've just installed a completely fresh installation of Blender 3.4.1 on a new PC. Every single tab except the shading tab works just fine, but when I click on shading, Blender closes completely without any explanation. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you please check if the graphics card drivers are up to date?

Comment: Windows update and the AMD software that was pre-installed both say I'm up to date.

Comment: Hello ! The shading tab by default is in lookdev mode which automatically loads all shaders under the eevee render engine. Does your file crash when you go into lookdev mode in other workspaces ?

Comment: Now that I check, yes. It does. Material preview and rendered preview both crash the program. Going to Render > Render Image also does this.